# Adding ACF field to post meta

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I found the code controlling the posts I need to edit:

```
$img = ( $mode == 'top' ) ? get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'large' ) : get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'medium' );

    $the_image = sprintf( '<span class="c_img">%s</span>', $img );

    $thumb_link = sprintf( '<a class="%s" href="%s" rel="bookmark" title="%s %s" style="%s">%s</a>', $classes, get_permalink( $post ), __( 'Link To', 'pagelines' ), the_title_attribute( array( 'echo' => false ) ), $style, $the_image );

    $output = ( 'top' == $mode ) ? sprintf( '<div class="full_img fix">%s</div>', $thumb_link ) : $thumb_link;

    return apply_filters( 'pagelines_thumb_markup', $output, $mode, $format );

}
```

That outputs like this:

```
<span class="c_img"><img src="example image"></span>
```

I need to insert my custom ACF (Advanced Custom Field) inside the span. The ACF field name is parent_category so it could be like this:

```
<span class="c_img"><i class="cat_tag">Deep House</i><img src="example image"></span>
```

So I need this to be injected in between there:

```
<i class="cat_tag"><?php the_field('parent_category'); ?></i>
```

How can i get this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I've glued up the relevant parts.  Please note my comments, which tell you what to change / what to add:

```
$img = ( $mode == 'top' ) ? get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'large' ) : get_the_post_thumbnail( null, 'medium' );

    // Add this line....(gets the markup you requested, and custom field value)
    $custom_field = '<i class="cat_tag">' . the_field('parent_category') . '</i>';
    // And modify this line.... (inserts it into the returned string)
    $the_image = sprintf( '<span class="c_img">%s%s</span>', $custom_field, $img );

    $thumb_link = sprintf( '<a class="%s" href="%s" rel="bookmark" title="%s %s" style="%s">%s</a>', $classes, get_permalink( $post ), __( 'Link To', 'pagelines' ), the_title_attribute( array( 'echo' => false ) ), $style, $the_image );

    $output = ( 'top' == $mode ) ? sprintf( '<div class="full_img fix">%s</div>', $custom_field, $thumb_link ) : $thumb_link;

    return apply_filters( 'pagelines_thumb_markup', $output, $mode, $format );
```